# Getting django-allauth to work with django-oidc-provider

Tags: openid-connect, django-allauth

I'm trying to get `django-allauth` to do user authentication against `django-oidc-provider`:

https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider

Like many OIDC providers, `django-oidc-provider` can serve a file which allows endpoint discovery.  For example:

`# http://localhost:8010/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration/`

```
{
    "issuer": "http://localhost:8010/openid",
    "authorization_endpoint": "http://localhost:8010/openid/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "http://localhost:8010/openid/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "http://localhost:8010/openid/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "http://localhost:8010/openid/end-session",
    "introspection_endpoint": "http://localhost:8010/openid/introspect",
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token",
        "code id_token token"
    ],
    "jwks_uri": "http://localhost:8010/openid/jwks",
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "HS256",
        "RS256"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "public"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_basic"
    ]
}
```

- Is there an existing `django-allauth` provider class that can parse and use the contents of an OIDC provider's `.well-known/openid-configuration` response?
- If not, is there an existing `django-allauth` provider class that would talk directly to a `django-oidc-provider`-powered OIDC provider, if I put the right stuff into `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS` in my project's `settings.py`?
- If not, what existing `django-allauth` provider class would you suggest I subclass/steal from, in order to add support to `django-allauth` for talking with `django-oidc-provider`?

(This question isn't 100% specific to `django-oidc-provider`.  Someone wanting to use some other provider unsupported by `django-allauth` would have the same question, for example, [Akana](https://help.akana.com/content/current/cm/api_oauth/oauth_discovery/m_oauth_getOpenIdConnectWellknownConfiguration.htm))

(see also [#676](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/676))

Answer (score 0):

As of `django-allauth` [0.52.0](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/releases/tag/0.52.0) there's a new [generic OpenID Connect provider](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/3165) that should be able to consume the `.well-known/openid-configuration` from your IdP.